# I want to calculate an average in Pandas with specific conditions but I don't know how

Tags: pandas, average

Imagine I have 1 main oven consisting of 3 sub ovens numbered with 1, 2 and 3:

```
   sub_oven_number  end_temp end_temp_registration  expected mean
0                1       700            2022-01-04  700 
1                2       650            2022-01-05  675 #(700+650)/2
2                3       630            2022-01-06  660 #(700+650+630)/3
3                1       720            2022-01-07  666.67 # (650+630+720)/3
4                2       550            2022-01-08  633.33 # (630+720+550)/3 
5                1       800            2022-01-09  660 # (630+800+550)/3
```

The column 'expected mean' shows what I want to achieve. Every time an oven is ready and registers a new temperature, it overwrites its old observation and a new mean is calculated.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without a sufficient understanding of the problem.  Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: `df['end_temp'].astype(float).expanding(3).mean()`

Comment: when is an oven skipped?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your dataset keeping the index, then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) the previous temperature values and aggregate per row with [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
df['mean'] = (df.pivot(columns='sub_oven_number', values='end_temp')
                .ffill().mean(axis=1).round(2)
             )
```

Output:

```
   sub_oven_number  end_temp end_temp_registration  expected_mean    mean
0                1       700            2022-01-04         700.00  700.00
1                2       650            2022-01-05         675.00  675.00
2                3       630            2022-01-06         660.00  660.00
3                1       720            2022-01-07         666.67  666.67
4                2       550            2022-01-08         633.33  633.33
5                1       800            2022-01-09         660.00  660.00
```

Intermediate:

```
df.pivot(columns='sub_oven_number', values='end_temp').ffill()

sub_oven_number      1      2      3
0                700.0    NaN    NaN
1                700.0  650.0    NaN
2                700.0  650.0  630.0
3                720.0  650.0  630.0
4                720.0  550.0  630.0
5                800.0  550.0  630.0
```

Comment: I edited the question and added your output with the mean I would expect based on my question. I hope this clarifies!

Comment: @Worstenbrood96 it does, this is a fully different logic. See update ;)